# Access parent attribute in d3.js to set attribute of child

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have (part of) HTML here:

```
<g style="fill: rgb(49, 130, 189);" transform="translate(0,0)" x="200" class="chr">
    <circle cy="175.92776604033872" r="3"></circle>
    <circle cy="292.4129588695106" r="3"></circle>
</g>
```

I am trying to set the cx attribute of the circles, for which I need to access to the `x` attibute of the parent. My code is given below:

```
ch.selectAll('circle')
    .data((d) => {
      return d.values;
    })
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('r', 3)
    .attr('cx', (d) => {
      ...
    })
    .attr('cy', (d) => {
      return y(d.num);
    });
```

Does anyone know how I can get the value of `x` attribute when setting the `cx` value? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Just a tip, not related to your question: g elements don't have x or y position.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Funnily enough, I also brought this to the user's attention some days ago in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544504/reading-csv-data-to-display-in-scatter-plot-with-d3-js#comment64484402_38544504)  to the same code in another question of theirs. On the other hand, these attributes are meaningless and will do no harm to the SVG, but it may be some means to convey informtation like Mark mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, you can use it to store information. But I think that coders and programmers should use the same *language*: when one sees "x" in a SVG, one thinks about x position...

Answer (score 6):

*Taking into consideration @GerardoFurtado's comment, I'll assume you are stashing that x value there for other reasons then positioning...*

You can access the parent (and the x attribute) as:

```
.attr('cx', function(d) {
  var parentXValue = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("x");
})
```

Comment: Upvoted. I didn't test that, but do fat arrows work alright with `this` in that situation?

Comment: Good point by @GerardoFurtado! `this` will not refer to the element when using fat arrow function. You will need a normal function expression instead.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado and altocumulus, thanks for catching that!  Fixed my answer.